# Accessing graph bundle property type, to use it in SFINAE

Tags: c++, type-traits, boost-graph

I have some code that can handle different types of (boost)graphs, and I want to do something special for graphs having some specific bundle property.

For example, this:

```
struct VertexProp
{
    // some data
};
```

My code can use two types of graphs:

```
using graph1_t  = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS,
    VertexProp
    > ;
```

or

```
using graph2_t = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS,
    boost::vecS,
    boost::undirectedS
    > ;
```

My intent is to use SFINAE to enable a function that will only handle this specific case:

```
template<Graph_t>
void foo
(
    const Graph_t& gr,
    std::enable_if<
        std::is_equal<SOME_TRAIT<Graph_t>::type,VertexProp>,T
        >::type* = nullptr
)
{
    // do something only for graphs having VertexProp
}
```

I'm ok with type traits in the general case (at least, I think so...), but in this case it's a third party type (`boost::adjacency_list`).

And I can't find in [the provided traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_traits.html) the typedef giving me that type.
I also checked [the included code](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp) in the manual, but didn't help.

How can I access that type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type via the `property_map` trait. In fact the value-type is a trait of that property map :)

So to detect the vertex bundle:

```
template <typename Graph, typename Bundle = typename boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_bundle_t>::type>
    using VBundle = typename boost::property_traits<Bundle>::value_type;
```

Making that more readable with whitespace:

```
template <
    typename Graph,
    typename Bundle = 
        typename boost::property_map<Graph, boost::vertex_bundle_t>::type>
using VBundle =
    typename boost::property_traits<Bundle>::value_type;
```

You can see that we ask the `property_traits` of the `vertex_bundle_t` property-map.

To check that it is the expected type:

```
template <typename Graph>
    using HasVertexProp = std::is_same<VertexProp, VBundle<Graph> >;
```

Now you can use SFINAE. Or, as I'd sugegst for a case like this: tag dispatch;

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename Graph_t>
    void foo(const Graph_t& g, std::true_type) {
        print_graph(g, std::cout << "Graph with VertexProp bundle: ");
    }

    template <typename Graph_t>
    void foo(const Graph_t& g, std::false_type) {
        print_graph(g, std::cout << "Graph with other/missing properties: ");
    }
}

template <typename Graph_t>
void foo(const Graph_t& g) {
    detail::foo(g, HasVertexProp<Graph_t>{});
}
```

Let's test it:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44673e4870259999)**

```
int main() {
    graph1_t g1(4);
    graph2_t g2(4);
    foo(g1);
    foo(g2);
}
```

Prints

```
Graph with VertexProp bundle: 0 <--> 
1 <--> 
2 <--> 
3 <--> 
Graph with other/missing properties: 0 <--> 
1 <--> 
2 <--> 
3 <-->
```

Comment: Thanks (again) Sehe, you're my true BGL guru ! ;-) I'll check that out carefully. I like the tag dispatch approach.

Comment: @kebs By the way I hope you have more types in the mix, because otherwise you could simply `foo(graph1_t){}; foo(graph2_t);` :) But yeah, this even works for other models: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/348a8880c023a4b9

Comment: Ah, yes, overloading, of course. Maybe I wanted to make things too complicated, indeed.

Comment: Actually, I can't use overloading in my use case, because the code is actually part of a library, and it's only for some specific "showcase" that I need to have a bundle property (and detect it). But in the general case, I need to stick to a general graph type, thus I'll stick to the approach you describe.

Comment: ok, just tried that, works perfectly, very elegant solution! Thanks a lot. Again, finding the information in the BGL manual is not easy. (for reference, its here:https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html#sec:property-map-types )

Comment: @kebs That's because it's not part of BGL. It's a separate library [Boost Propertymap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html) because it's way more reusable - in effect it's not dissimilar to Lenses in FP  languages (like Haskell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template template parameter to name the nested types of some `Graph_t`, and then sfinae on whether any of the nested types are `VertexProp`, like this:

```
template<template<typename ...> class Graph_t, typename ...Props>
auto foo(Graph_t<Props...>) 
  -> std::enable_if_t<
      std::disjunction<std::is_same<VertexProp, Props>...>{}>
{}
```

and you get:

```
foo(graph1_t{});  // ok
foo(graph2_t{});  // error
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll need some time to analyse this.

Comment: Sure. Feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: This will also pick up if another template argument matches. It's better to go through the library's traits.

Comment: @sehe I'm not sure what you mean. This checks if *any of* the template arguments match.

Comment: Precisely. It doesn't check whether that argument defines the vertex property bundle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be misunderstanding something. Is this something to do with `boost` specifically? My answer doesn't take that into account.

Comment: Many boost libraries have types taking many template arguments, often in varying orders. How the library interprets them is important to the question. The question is not "Does the argument list contain a specific type" but "Is the property bundle type XXX". It's a different question and the answers may differ.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. I'll leave this answer up anyway, as it might be useful to the OP.

Comment: @cigien yep it is ! Didn't know about [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction).